# how to set a data-id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to set `data-id` after the user put a URL in an input, already tried a lot of samples that I found here and none of these worked...

```js
//https://imgur.com/SPrSZV7 im trying with this url
function getUrl() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txtURL').value;
  var novaURL = txt.replace('https://imgur.com/', '');
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = novaURL;
  imagem = document.getElementById('imagem').setAttribute('data-id', novaURL);
}
```

```html
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<input type="text" id="txtURL">
<input onclick="getUrl()" type="submit">
<h3 id="resultado">Resultado:</h3>
<blockquote id="imagem" class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="">
</blockquote>
```

the `data-id` should be `SPrSZV7`, I got in the console the error `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null`, why is this null?

Comment: did you pass your JS code before body code ?

Comment: no, my js code is above the body

Comment: so that's why document.getElementById ('imagem') is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is the `imgur` embed library is loading and overwriting your `blockquote` with an `iframe`, so your `ID` of `"imagem"` disappears when the `iframe` loads in its place. Trying wrapping the `blockquote` with a `div` container that has `data-id` attribute, and setting the `data` value there for reference. Or you can try and reference the imgur `iframe` ID that appears when embed happens: `'imgur-embed-iframe-pub-'` instead of using a `div` wrapper. Please see the following example:

```js
//https://imgur.com/SPrSZV7 im trying with this url
function getUrl() {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txtURL').value;
  var novaURL = txt.replace('https://imgur.com/', '');
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = novaURL;
  var imagem = document.getElementById('container-for-imgur');
  imagem.dataset.id = novaURL;
  console.log(imagem.dataset.id);
}
```

```html
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtURL" value="https://imgur.com/SPrSZV7" />
<input onclick="getUrl()" type="submit" />
<h3 id="resultado">Resultado:</h3>
<div id="container-for-imgur" data-id="">
  <blockquote id="imagem" class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="">
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: i think i understood the problem, maybe works if a remove the blockquote tag and create a new one with the data-id of ``novaURL`` when i press the button?

Comment: That could work, but it looks like you still need an element in which to load the imgur `iframe` into the DOM, which the `blockquote` is currently doing.

Comment: also i tried with your code and got 1 error when the page loads, ``Uncaught ReferenceError: _widgetFactory is not defined``

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not seeing that in the code snippet I created with the code you provided. Are you loading other libraries that aren't in your current code example you gave us?

Comment: all i got is [this](https://codepen.io/igorestevao/pen/dLxNxX), i was thinking this gonna be a easy to solve

Comment: Your codepen is working the same way as my snippet, correctly. The `_widgetFactory` error is because you're loading imgur embed library within codepen, I don't believe it has anything to do with your actual code. I see the error here under snippets as well: `<anonymous> https://imgur.com//embed?ref=https://stacksnippets.net/js&w=540:101`

Comment: tbh I gave up, I decided to do it in php, everything is working, but I got a problem to display blockquote tag, I'm going to ask a new question soon, also thx for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> why is this null?

because you pass your JS code before body code ?

---

use dataset => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

```
document.getElementById('imagem').dataset.id = novaURL;
```

remark : there is no return value so do not use  `imagem =`

Comment: hey! i got this error from console: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
maybe data-id does not work with blockquote?

Comment: **remark : there is no return value so do not use imagem =**

Comment: So, your error message say Cannot read property 'setAttribute' **of null** that mean **document.getElementById('imagem') is  null**

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. You can see in inspect that the data attribute is correctly set up. You must have been experiencing a script load problem in which the content DOM is not loaded before the script execution.

```js
    //https://imgur.com/SPrSZV7 im trying with this url
    function getUrl() {
        var txt = document.getElementById('txtURL').value;
        var novaURL = txt.replace('https://imgur.com/', '');
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = novaURL;
        imagem = document.getElementById('imagem').setAttribute('data-id', novaURL);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtURL">
    <input onclick="getUrl()" type="submit">
    <h3 id="resultado">Resultado:</h3>
    <blockquote id="imagem" class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="">
    </blockquote>
```

Comment: you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: See @Woodrow answer.